# A number puzzle with an emoji

Tags: mathematics

What number should be in the question mark and why? (My original puzzle)

-12=98

25+16=13

+27+42=120

+91+90=?

Hints:

> Each number (before the equal sign) has the same operation done to it

> Think about 'smaller numbers' that can 'move'

> Left to right

> 'In the seas' - a wee pun

Comment: How do I give it a bounty?

Comment: You can make a bounty after 48 hours the question was asked.

Comment: I think you should put a hint

Comment: I have given one upvote, give me the hint lol
anything related to xor /xnor so that we think in that direction

Comment: can you describe more about what is meant by move

Comment: It is usually a rude expression directed at an ignorant occupier of anothers beloved and often merely self-entitled seat. If I may presume that the context surrounding this question is of am incompetent speaker of the English language befuddled by the irascible words of an irate Englishman, then I am afraid to inform you that you have been accosted in a very insolent manner by a very rude gentleman. Sorry to unravel the constituents of an incident that will surely harm your perceptions of the Anglophone world. If you do see that man or woman again I would advise that you demand an apology...

Comment: Also to potentially satitiate one's agony born from the many laborious hours poured onto this rather trivial puzzle I shall provide yet another hint.

Comment: Who keeps on giving this puzzle a downvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have the answer:

> It is 101

Because:

> Firstly the smiley face is 100

> Next In each number the first digit is placed as the power of the second digit.

> Finally all the digits of the resulting numbers are added together.

Comment: Wow that has taken a while